# Akka Streams High CPU Utilization and too many threads being created

Tags: akka, cpu, akka-stream

I have an Consumer using akka streams where we are consuming packets from kafka. The number of threads are in several thousands and always increasing.

Tried taking thread dump where we found two kinds of threads which have maxiumum count :

Following is the config file

```
akka.kafka.consumer {
  # Tuning property of scheduled polls.
  # Controls the interval from one scheduled poll to the next.
  poll-interval = 250ms

  # Tuning property of the `KafkaConsumer.poll` parameter.
  # Note that non-zero value means that the thread that
  # is executing the stage will be blocked. See also the `wakup-timeout` setting below.
  poll-timeout = 50ms

  # The stage will delay stopping the internal actor to allow processing of
  # messages already in the stream (required for successful committing).
  # Prefer use of `DrainingControl` over a large stop-timeout.
  stop-timeout = 30s

  # Duration to wait for `KafkaConsumer.close` to finish.
  close-timeout = 20s

  # If offset commit requests are not completed within this timeout
  # the returned Future is completed `CommitTimeoutException`.
  # The `Transactional.source` waits this amount of time for the producer to mark messages as not
  # being in flight anymore as well as waiting for messages to drain, when rebalance is triggered.
  commit-timeout = 15s

  # If commits take longer than this time a warning is logged
  commit-time-warning = 1s

  # Not used anymore (since 1.0-RC1)
  # wakeup-timeout = 3s

  # Not used anymore (since 1.0-RC1)
  # max-wakeups = 10

  # If set to a finite duration, the consumer will re-send the last committed offsets periodically
  # for all assigned partitions. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4682.
  commit-refresh-interval = infinite

  # Not used anymore (since 1.0-RC1)
  # wakeup-debug = true

  # Fully qualified config path which holds the dispatcher configuration
  # to be used by the KafkaConsumerActor. Some blocking may occur.
  use-dispatcher = "akka.default-dispatcher"

  # Properties defined by org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig
  # can be defined in this configuration section.
  kafka-clients {
    # Disable auto-commit by default
    enable.auto.commit = false
  }

  # Time to wait for pending requests when a partition is closed
  wait-close-partition = 500ms

  # Limits the query to Kafka for a topic's position
  position-timeout = 5s

  # When using `AssignmentOffsetsForTimes` subscriptions: timeout for the
  # call to Kafka's API
  offset-for-times-timeout = 5s

  # Timeout for akka.kafka.Metadata requests
  # This value is used instead of Kafka's default from `default.api.timeout.ms`
  # which is 1 minute.
  metadata-request-timeout = 5s

  # Interval for checking that transaction was completed before closing the consumer.
  # Used in the transactional flow for exactly-once-semantics processing.
  eos-draining-check-interval = 30ms
}


#####################################
# Akka Stream Reference Config File #
#####################################

akka {
  stream {

    # Default materializer settings
    materializer {

      # Initial size of buffers used in stream elements
      initial-input-buffer-size = 4
      # Maximum size of buffers used in stream elements
      max-input-buffer-size = 8

      # Fully qualified config path which holds the dispatcher configuration
      # to be used by ActorMaterializer when creating Actors.
      # When this value is left empty, the default-dispatcher will be used.
      dispatcher = "akka.default-dispatcher"

      # Cleanup leaked publishers and subscribers when they are not used within a given
      # deadline
      subscription-timeout {
        # when the subscription timeout is reached one of the following strategies on
        # the "stale" publisher:
        # cancel - cancel it (via `onError` or subscribing to the publisher and
        #          `cancel()`ing the subscription right away
        # warn   - log a warning statement about the stale element (then drop the
        #          reference to it)
        # noop   - do nothing (not recommended)
        mode = cancel

        # time after which a subscriber / publisher is considered stale and eligible
        # for cancelation (see `akka.stream.subscription-timeout.mode`)
        timeout = 5s
      }

      # Enable additional troubleshooting logging at DEBUG log level
      debug-logging = off

      # Maximum number of elements emitted in batch if downstream signals large demand
      output-burst-limit = 1000

      # Enable automatic fusing of all graphs that are run. For short-lived streams
      # this may cause an initial runtime overhead, but most of the time fusing is
      # desirable since it reduces the number of Actors that are created.
      # Deprecated, since Akka 2.5.0, setting does not have any effect.
      auto-fusing = on

      # Those stream elements which have explicit buffers (like mapAsync, mapAsyncUnordered,
      # buffer, flatMapMerge, Source.actorRef, Source.queue, etc.) will preallocate a fixed
      # buffer upon stream materialization if the requested buffer size is less than this
      # configuration parameter. The default is very high because failing early is better
      # than failing under load.
      #
      # Buffers sized larger than this will dynamically grow/shrink and consume more memory
      # per element than the fixed size buffers.
      max-fixed-buffer-size = 1000000000

      # Maximum number of sync messages that actor can process for stream to substream communication.
      # Parameter allows to interrupt synchronous processing to get upsteam/downstream messages.
      # Allows to accelerate message processing that happening withing same actor but keep system responsive.
      sync-processing-limit = 1000

      debug {
        # Enables the fuzzing mode which increases the chance of race conditions
        # by aggressively reordering events and making certain operations more
        # concurrent than usual.
        # This setting is for testing purposes, NEVER enable this in a production
        # environment!
        # To get the best results, try combining this setting with a throughput
        # of 1 on the corresponding dispatchers.
        fuzzing-mode = off
      }
    }

    # Fully qualified config path which holds the dispatcher configuration
    # to be used by ActorMaterializer when creating Actors for IO operations,
    # such as FileSource, FileSink and others.
    blocking-io-dispatcher = "akka.stream.default-blocking-io-dispatcher"

    default-blocking-io-dispatcher {
      type = "Dispatcher"
      executor = "thread-pool-executor"
      throughput = 1

      thread-pool-executor {
        fixed-pool-size = 16
      }
    }
  }

  # configure overrides to ssl-configuration here (to be used by akka-streams, and akka-http – i.e. when serving https connections)
  ssl-config {
    protocol = "TLSv1.2"
  }
}


ssl-config {
  logger = "com.typesafe.sslconfig.akka.util.AkkaLoggerBridge"
}

akka.default-dispatcher {
  type = "Dispatcher"

  executor = "thread-pool-executor"

  thread-pool-executor {
    # minimum number of threads to cap factor-based core number to
    core-pool-size-min = 5
    # No of core threads ... ceil(available processors * factor)
    core-pool-size-factor = 2.0
    # maximum number of threads to cap factor-based number to
    core-pool-size-max = 20
  }
  # Throughput defines the maximum number of messages to be
  # processed per actor before the thread jumps to the next actor.
  # Set to 1 for as fair as possible.
  throughput = 5
}
```

Following are the errors with maximum thread count :

one is :

priority:5 - threadId:0x00007f9414008800 - nativeId:0x5575 - nativeId (decimal):21877 - state:WAITING
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for <0x0000000740597170> (a akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinPool)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:2075)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Locked ownable synchronizers:

Other is :

default-scheduler-1
priority:5 - threadId:0x00007f947805d800 - nativeId:0x638a - nativeId (decimal):25482 - state:TIMED_WAITING
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler.waitNanos(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:87)
at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$3.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:271)
at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$3.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:241)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Locked ownable synchronizers:
- None

The CPU utilization is going till 800 %. What is it that is causing such a high CPU Utilization. Please advise.

Comment: can you post a code snippet?
It is possibly because you may be running lot async tasks(futures)

Comment: Thanks, found the solution. Actually default dispatcher and scheduler were being created apart from a custom dispatcher. Default dispatcher can create unneccesary threads which were leading to thread starvation and using all the resources.